# Steps to add splash screen in Ionic app using vs2015?

Tags: visual-studio, ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015

Steps to add splash screen in Ionic app using vs2015 ?

I tried google it but every where it was by using CLI

Answer (score 0):

And then why you don't use just a comandline tool?

Comment: Thanx....I am done with that...I was expecting visual studio must be having something on a click of a button.

Answer (score 0):

In your resource folder look for **ionic.png** and **splash.png** and replace the image with your image.

***NOTE***:
STEP-1 : Your ionic icon image should be **1024pixels** and your splashscreen image should be **2208pixels**.

STEP-2 : Go to your project folder and then run **ionic resources**.

For more information look in to http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/icon-splashscreen.html

It worked for me,hope it will work for you.